# Как на JavaScript прочитать значения переменных с одинаковыми именами?

Tags: javascript, actionscript, actionscript-3, actionscript-2

Есть три переменные с одинаковым именем (value), но с разными значениями. Как из вложенной функции можно все эти три переменные прочитать?

(вопрос не практический, а теоретический, поэтому предложения назвать их по-разному, передавать в параметрах принимаемых функциями и т.п. не подходят. То что хочется понять - это именно использовать по аналогии с AS - примеры ниже)

```
var value = "global"
function f1() {
    var value = "external";

    function f2() {
        var value = "internal";

        alert(any code 1?) // global
        alert(any code 2?) // external
        alert(any code 3?) // internal
    }
}
```

На ActionScript это достаточно легко:

```
var _value = "global"

function f1() {
    var _value = "external";

    function f2() {
        var ext=_value
        var _value = "internal";

        trace(_root._value)     // works: global
        trace(ext)              // works: external
        trace(_value)           // works: internal
    }
    f2()
}
f1()
```

Также в ActionScript можно использовать объект активации (но в JS насколько я знаю доступа к нему нет):

```
var _value = "global"

function f1() {
    var _value = "external";

    function f2() {
        _value // связываем объект активации f1 с f2
        var _value = "internal";

        trace(_root._value)     // works: global
        trace(this._value)      // works: external
        trace(_value)           // works: internal      
    }
    f2()
}
f1()
```

Comment: назвать их по разному.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

C global все легко, на месте root стоит объект window. 
С internal тоже все ясно, тут особо думать не надо.
А вот с external придется использовать хаки, как впрочем и в AS.

```
var value = "global"
function f1() {
    var value = "external";
    var val = value; 
    function f2() {
        var value = "internal";

        console.log(window.value);
        console.log(val);
        console.log(value);
    }
}
```

P.S. хотя мне кажется внутри f2 вы "external" уже никак не получите, так как ссылка мгновенно затирается при одном только упоминании `var value`.

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто вызвать f2 с параметром value.
Выводится "global external internal"

```
var value = "global";
function f1() {
    var value = "external";
    function f2() {
        var value = "internal";
        alert(window.value + " " + arguments[0] + " " + value);
    }
    f2(value);
}
f1();
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать такую интересную возможность *JavaScript* как замыкания:

```js
var value = "global";

function f1()
{
    var value = "external";

    var f1_value = function() {
        return value;
    };

    function f2() 
    {
        var value = "internal";

        document.body.innerHTML = 
            window.value + "<br />" +  // global
            f1_value()   + "<br />" +  // external
            value;                     // internal
    }

    f2();
}
```

```html
<body onload="f1();">
    
</body>
```